# Making connections abroad

Tags: visa, working-visas, south-africa

I am a recent graduate from an American University, and I am looking to travel abroad. I am not looking to move away permanently, but I would like to work for a few years in a different place. I work as a software developer, so it seems that I would have opportunity to find work elsewhere. The problem I am running into is that I have no connections in the foreign country which I would want to work in (South Africa, specifically). I do not know the best way to find connections overseas without knowing someone directly.

I have been told that it would be beneficial for me to look into work for American companies which have operations internationally rather than to try and find local companies, as this will make for easier connections back home.

What resources, sites, and methods would one use to effectively find international work?

Comment: Currently there are so many possible ways, that it could lead to many answers, which is not a great fit for a Stackexchange question.

Comment: I'd consider international job sites, and conencting to recruiters on linkedin, which has worked for me moving countries several times.